# Span dont show up

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I fetch strigns from a json file and look for the string in the html. then i surround it with

```
<span id='thisSpan' onmouseover='correctSentence()' style='background-color: yellow;'></span>
```

when i inspect the text is surrounded but its not highlighted.

Here's my code

this is how i fetch data from json

```
function loadCorrections(){
highlights = [];
  $.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
  });
  $.getJSON('link', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
        if(data[index].highlight != null){
          var text = data[index].highlight;
          text = text.split('"').join('');
          highlights.push(text);
        }
      });
  });
  $.ajaxSetup({
      async: true
  });
}
```

and this is how i surround it inn HTML

```
function highlightErrors(){
  document.getElementById("correct").checked = true;
  loadCorrections();
    var txt = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var innerHTML = txt.innerHTML;
  for(i=0;i<highlights.length;i++){
    var text = highlights[i];
    var index = innerHTML.indexOf(highlights[i]);
    if (index >= 0) { 
      try{
        innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(text,"<span id='thisSpan' onmouseover='correctSentence()' style='background-color: yellow;'> "+text+" </span>");
        
      }catch(error){
        alert(error);
      }
    }
    txt.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
```

[image: This is the text surrounded with the spa element but still my text is not highlighted]

Comment: Within `highlightErrors` you reference a variable `highlights` - is that globally defined?

Comment: Also - you cannot have multiple elements with the same, duplicated ID. Remove the ID from the replacement string

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes it is globally defined.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius so how can i get the text inside a span onmouseover

Comment: The problem is perhaps the asynchronous nature of AJAX. `loadCorrections` might NOT have finished by the time the rest of the code within `highlightErrors` has finished.

Comment: The function is triggered when selecting a radio button but when the radio isnt checked and the function doesnt throw any error.

Comment: but i set the async to false. should i leave it as it is?